# Call to undefined function pspell_check() php version 5.6.25

Tags: php

I've been cleaning up some code and ran into this error.

```
Call to undefined function pspell_check() in ___.php on line _
```

I seem to be missing the pspell_check() function, though I was under the impression that php version 5.6.25 should have this it. Here is the line in question, if it helps.

```
$checkedWord = pspell_check($dict, $word);
```

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Does `phpinfo();` show the pspell library?

Comment: Follow these steps: http://php.net/manual/en/pspell.installation.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `pspell` may not have been installed correctly. Are you perhaps missing `aspell`?

This is listed as a dependency in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pspell.requirements.php).

You may also need to build PHP with the `--with-pspell[=dir]` per the [installation docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pspell.installation.php)